# RegEx: Replace lines that start with "msgctxt" with content that is in between quotation marks of those strings

Tags: regex, notepad++, po

I have several big files with several entries like these:

```
msgctxt "#. client error message"
msgctxt "#. 0 = ID"
#: Some more text
msgid ""
"Could not activate\n"
"Connection lost?"
msgstr ""
"Some other text"
"Even more other text"
```

Now, ideally, I would like all of the lines that start with "msgctxt" to be replaced with the content that is in between the quotation marks of those strings:

```
#. client error message
#. 0 = ID
#: Some more text
msgid ""
"Could not activate\n"
"Connection lost?"
msgstr ""
"Some other text"
"Even more other text"
```

Some entries don't have any "msgctxt", others have only one or several.

Is there a way to do this with Regular Expressions in Notepad++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that a simple expression such as,

```
msgctxt\s+"(.+)"
```

being replaced by $1 would simply suffice.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BmDX02/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much! This does exactly what I wanted. I also like the website you shared, thanks.